# Orchard CMS - Navigation does not work anymore

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, navigation, orchardcms

I am new to Orchard CMS system. http://www.orchardproject.net

I installed Version 1.0 and now they updated and I installed version 1.1.30 but never really published something.

I downloaded Navigation Feature *"Advanced menu - Version: 1.2.1"* and I saw some menu items to use and tried something. But **I could not delete them anymore**.

If I disable and enable I receive error:

```
    In einen eindeutigen Index kann kein doppelter Wert eingefügt werden. 
[ Table name = Szmyd_Orchard_Modules_Menu_AdvancedMenuPartRecord,Constraint 
name = UQ__Szmyd_Orchard_Modules_Menu_AdvancedMenuPartRecord__0000000000000352 ]
```

But I can see Navigation menu with advanced subitems.

I don't know where the menu gots his information from but some items like "Sprecher" is on the "Advanced menu Navigation" but when I click delete the error occours:

```
404 - Datei oder Verzeichnis wurde nicht gefunden.
```

I have tried several days for any solution without success. Please help.

Comment: Thanks, I'll investigate this issue and keep you posted with a solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot pszmyd. I already searched for several days for any solution. Please can you provide me the location where the items are stored? If it will keep simple for you, I can offer to watch via remote desktop.

Comment: Hi, I traced the errors you provided. First one touches the creation of default navigation menu at 'enabling' step (which throws a error as 'main' menu already exists and menu name column is supposed to be unique). So just don't worry about that. (although I'll fix that). The error with deleting items was also reported by a few other people and it happens because of invalid anti-forgery token in URL. I'll fix that too (possibly tomorrow) and keep you posted. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I managed to find out the sources of the problems and both will be fixed in the upcoming release. I'll try to do it by the end of this week.**

**First issue**

Don't worry with the error you encountered after disabling and enabling the module - it's one time and doesn't affect module usage (but will be fixed, of course).

*Disabling a module doesn't delete any underlying database tables - it's just telling the framework not to use the module code. The default menu gets created at the Enabling step, and sits there even if you disable the module. Unfortunately, it's not checking whether the menu has already been created, so every time you enable the module it shouts about "trying to insert a duplicate in unique index" (menu name is unique).*

**Second issue**

You can apply this fix to allow deleting menus.
Go to *[Root]/Modules/Szmyd.Orchard.Modules.Menu/Views/MenuAdmin/Index.cshtml* and replace

```
@Html.ActionLink(T("Delete menu").Text, "Delete", "MenuAdmin", new { Area = "Szmyd.Orchard.Modules.Menu" }, new { @class = "button primaryAction" })
```

with:

```
<a href="@Html.AntiForgeryTokenGetUrl(Url.Action("Delete", new { menuName = Model.MenuName }))" class="button primaryAction">@T("Delete menu") </a>
```

This will make delete links render correctly.

**UPDATE**

I forgot to add that some people reported that *Delete* operation won't work with menu called *'main'*. I investigated the issue and found the source(s) of a problem.

**First**

The problem with the main menu is that, the **"Main menu" link in admin Dashboard is always there, whether you delete the menu or not**. This link is being added by the old, default Orchard navigation system, but url to where it leads is overwritten by Advanced Menu module.

**Second**

After deleting the menu, corresponding menu items are not deleted. Items are connected with the corresponding menu by it's name, so if you delete 'main' menu, all items connected to 'main' are still there, after the menu itself got deleted. That's why after clicking the "Main menu" you suddenly see all menu items as if nothing happened. **But clicking "Delete menu" will throw you a nice 404 error, because menu itself not exists.**

I'll address all of these issues asap and publish a fix.

Comment: Hi pszmyd. Let me thank you very much for your response. I've tried to change the Index.cshtml file. It was clearly and easy. But The problem still occour. Page not found, when clicking on Delete button. Perhaps, if it is allowed, I can share my situation by Teamviewer. It would be great if I could setup the page now (I am waiting for several month to do this because of menus). I still did not really understand where menus are stored.

Comment: Exact error "Error 404- File or Folder not found", URL: h**p://domain.ch/page/Admin/Navigation/main/Delete?__RequestVerificationToken=20T9ztSTXMiN%2f8thCXIdTjrInObPJ0VEstAf0L0%2bML5b3kn6A1XMCKvctqhiwwIa0nlKsNQkD61aoamh%2fXYjND0ATPMVRQfadaCuDQvJJz9WaR1aJEwGym9jesQf%2btDUYF8W3AQFBl%2fl2MXkXUxx5AhBZf8W6C4%2fMW6efGP7Nr6BnAS1BdiC57Q6T0FQilgPvkXrjXqTR4wUuTPkpB5xjA%3d%3d

Comment: Some people reported that deleting won't work with menu called 'main' (the default one). It's weird, as it's just an ordinary menu, like every other, just called 'main'. I have to track that down - I have a suspicion that there's some routing problem, as the built-in Orchard menu system (the simple one you get at start) uses similar routes. Try creating a new menu and see whether deleting it also ends with 404 error, ok? If not - you can simply ignore the 'main' menu and use the new one in widgets. I'll provide a fix to that in upcoming release.

Comment: The menus and menu items are both Orchard content types. They are stored in two database tables - menus: Szmyd_Orchard_Modules_Menu_AdvancedMenuPartRecord, menu items: Szmyd_Orchard_Modules_Menu_AdvancedMenuItemPartRecord. In addition, the template for TemplatedMenuItem is stored in Common_BodyPart table (having the same Id as corresponding record in menu item table above).

Comment: If you are short on time, I'd advise you to ignore the problem with the 'main' menu. Just create a second menu, call it differently and use that instead. You can switch the menu which is displayed (from 'main' to the new one) in the MenuWidget/StyledMenuWidget properties.

Comment: Adding a new menu and adding items and deleting it works fine. After I've tried to delete the Main Menu again but still failed.

Comment: *revision* I could delete items. But the new Menu I've created is not deletable. I've tried to Go to "Widgets > Navigation > Add > Styled Menu Widget > Wrote similar like in Main Menu > Save. Please can you advice me how to proceed? Menu is not in Website yet.

Comment: I updated my answer. This is a bug that you can see the main menu at all. It's been already deleted, so any subsequent clicks on "Delete menu" will throw you a 404 (as the menu doesn't exist). You can see items from 'main' menu because, due to bug, they were not deleted with the corresponding menu. I wrote about that in update above.

Comment: Do it like this: 1. Create a new menu. To do that, go to Navigation > Create new menu. Enter some name you want, eg. "mymenu" and hit "Save". Go to Navigation > "<menu name you gave> Menu" (eg. "Mymenu Menu") and add all necessary items. 2. Update the existing widget (in Widgets pane) to display "mymenu" instead of "main" (name is case-sensitive). By default there should exist a Styled Menu Widget called "Main Menu" in Navigation zone. Edit it by clicking on it. If the widget do not exist (because was deleted), add one (Styled Menu Widget or Menu Widget). And that's all.

Comment: Hi pszmyd. Now it worked for current situation, thanks. It looks bad but this is because of any theme I know. http://www.goldengel.ch/temp/Menu_fault.PNG

Comment: This is because of default CSS styles applied in theme for 'nav' element. Open Site.css inside your theme (Styles/Site.css) and comment out/remove the styles starting with "nav (...)".